# Oracle Forms ON-LOCK/lock_record not working after set_record_property QUERY_STATUS

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

In a summary: I edited a database item, ON-LOCK trigger fired, and then executed:

`set_record_property(get_block_property('my_block', current_record),'my_block',status, QUERY_STATUS);`

And after that whenever I edit any database item in that record or even programmatically call LOCK_RECORD, the ON-LOCK trigger is not firing.

Why am I even doing this, is another story, but is there some other place (record property) where Forms store info that "this record has already been locked"?
There is no way that Forms check something in the database, because in my ON-LOCK trigger I have left just a debug message.

Answer (score 0):

ON-LOCK trigger should have the select '1' into dummy from yourTable where record_key = xxx for update nowait; statement. Check if you have that.

Comment: The first thing in the ON-LOCK trigger is my debug message. I don't see it. That is how I know that is not firing.